# Installed Nodeclipse on Eclipse Kepler, cannot turn off Java spell check

Tags: java, eclipse, nodeclipse, spelling

I added Nodeclipse "Enide Studio 2014" plugins to the same Workspace as my Java projects (I usually don't do that).

My Node Perspective worked great, I created a new Node project and it all worked great.

Then I went back to my Java Perspective and noticed that all of my Java projects had spell check enabled - the annotations "sp" were on the left margin for mundane names for variables all over the place.

I made sure spell check was disabled globally (Window - Preferences - General - Editors - Text Editors - Spelling).  Not enabled.  But still there in all my Java projects. How to turn (back) off without uninstalling Nodeclipse?

Comment: You had spelling mistakes listed in the Problems/Markers View in addition to the editor?

Comment: No, just the editor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you are adding plugins into Eclipse instance not workspace.
You can open workspace with different Eclipses,
and use the same Eclipse to open several workspaces in the same time.

[Nodeclipse "Enide Studio 2014"](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/) comes with [JDT-spelling](https://github.com/hendrens/jdt.spelling), that checks for words inside Java names using conventions , see [#30](https://github.com/stuarthendren/jdt.spelling/issues/30)

[image]

To disable or configure go to

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> JDT Spelling

(or just search for "spell" in Preferences Dialog)

Answer (score 5):

If you update to the latest JDT-Spelling you can disable the whole plugin in the preferences

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> JDT Spelling

Or maybe better still, if this is not a feature you want just uninstall the JDT-Spelling plugin from your eclipse installation.

Eclipse's spelling support is a different service (and internal so difficult to extend) so disabling it has no effect on the JDT Spelling. If you just disabling the markers it will still be doing all that work to spellcheck your java names but you wont get any benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

While spell checking was disabled globally, in order to fully turn off spell checking, I had to disable the Java Spelling Marker in Annotations.  Yowsie.  Right here, do this:

Window - Preferences - General - Editors - Text Editors - Annotations

Then on the right side, scroll down to Java Spelling Marker, then on the right of that, uncheck all of these:

- Vertical ruler
- Overview ruler
- Text as

Gone - no more annotations of spelling "errors" from all those variable names in Eclipse/Java.